# Typescript convert object to Array

Tags: typescript

Trying to convert Javascript Object

```
const xyz = {
'fName': {type: 'string'},
'mName': {type: 'string'},
'lName': {type: 'string'}
};
```

To

```
const arr = [
{'fName': {type: 'string'}},
{'mName': {type: 'string'}},
{'lName': {type: 'string'}}
]
```

It looks like some logic I'm missing today, tried online lot of blgs but didn't get anything(tough day).

Please someone tell me why I am not able to convert.

Comment: Please (re)take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go.

```js
const xyz = {
'fName': {type: 'string'},
'mName': {type: 'string'},
'lName': {type: 'string'}
};

let arr = [];

for(let k in xyz) {
  arr.push({[k] : xyz[k]});
}

console.log("Object", xyz);
console.log("Array", arr);
```